# Difference betweeen atomism and mereological nihilism

Tags: metaphysics, nihilism, atomism

Is *mereological nihilism,* the metaphysical doctrine that objects with proper parts do not exist, the same as *atomism?* If not, what are the differences?

How can mereological nihilism work without assuming that there are at some point only objects which do not contain parts, i.e. philosophical atoms (things that are not composed, which means undividable)? If philosophical atoms do not exist, it would follow from mereological nihilism that *nothing* does exist, because *everything* has proper parts.

Comment: Atomists do not hold that tables and chairs do not exist because they have parts, indeed they consider atoms to be parts of everything. And the way mereological nihilism works is e.g. by reinterpreting 'there are tables' a la van Inwagen, as 'there are simples arranged tablewise', so "nothing is" does not follow. The difference with mereology would not show at the common sense level, it only affects some subtle philosophical issues.

Comment: @Conifold: what about *entailment,* does mereological nihilism not entail atomism?

Comment: You seem to use "entailment" in some special way, if so please explain what it is. On colloquial meaning I do not see what difference it makes, so no.